# Violation on primary key with multiple keys in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE parameters (
  tag_id BIGINT,
  id NVARCHAR(255),
  idx NVARCHAR(255),
  primary key (tag_id, idx)
);

CREATE TABLE tag
    ([oid] int, [Name] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO tag
    ([oid], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'D')
;

INSERT parameters (tag_id, id, idx)
SELECT tag.oid, id.a, idx.a
FROM 
    ( VALUES (1), (0), ('A'), (2) ) AS id(a), 
    ( VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d') ) AS idx(a), 
    tag
```

This should be output:

```
tag_id              id              idx     
______________________________________________
1                   1               a
1                   0               b
1                   A               c
1                   2               d
2                   1               a
2                   0               b
2                   A               c
2                   2               d
3                   1               a
3                   0               b
3                   A               c
3                   2               d
4                   1               a
4                   0               b
4                   A               c
4                   2               d
```

Below is the error which I am getting:

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'tag_parameters'. The duplicate
>   key value is (1, a).

Why if I have only one combination (1, a). The next one is (2, a).

Comment: That SQL doesn't generate that error, it generates `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc2b56732e8eff4b70df49ff84c66b8f)

Comment: Your are doing `CROSS JOIN` that cause the problem.

Comment: Besides, the error is pretty clear - that query generates duplicates. For every combination of `tag_id` and `idx`, you get 4 rows from the `id` values

Comment: Your `FROM` syntax is needlessly confusing/ambiguous. Use an explicit `CROSS JOIN` if that's what you really intended, but I'm betting it's not. If you comment out the `INSERT` you can see what you're actually trying to insert.

Comment: @Larnu huh... that's another problem. I don't know whay doesn't accept chars even the filed id is defined as nvarchar...

Comment: if you comment out the `INSERT`, @JeroenMostert , you *still* get a conversion error [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3455bc1754c0069f8d81ccd0584a92b). Really not sure what the OP is after.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the `INSERT` @Josef. it's to do with `SELECT id.a FROM (VALUES (1),(0),('A'),(2)) id (a);` You have two different data types there and only one column (`a`). `'A'` is *not* an integer, so it can't be converted to an `int`.

Comment: @Larnu: of course, but I just shrugged and fixed that by quoting everything. My psychic debugging senses tell me that the inadvertent `CROSS JOIN` with too many values is the actual problem, and if it's not, if the OP has an `INSERT` statement that produces a duplicate error, commenting out that part *will* tell them they have duplicates. Of course, it would be nice if the OP fixed the question so there's an actual repro.

Comment: You are creating a join without any ON statement. That's a full join with all the combinations. Try creating a temp table, and inserting it 4 times. Simpler, don't you think?

Comment: @LongChalk A full join is a type of outer join - it is very different from a cross join.

Comment: @SMor, true, but they both produce a Cartesian join in this case. Join a 4 line table with a 5 line table without an ON statement and you'll get 20 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same column `idx` in single `values` construct :

```
SELECT t.oid, a.id, a.idx
FROM tag t CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES ('1', 'a'), ('0', 'b'), ('A', 'c'), ('2', 'd') 
    ) AS a(id, idx);
```